# Initial production build creates bundle code, but all subsequent builds reuse old bundle

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, sails.js, babeljs

After adding authentication with passport and redux to my project, anytime I push my production ready code to my server it reuses an old build of the bundle file. If I use a one off server that had a much older build of the project it creates a new bundle, but any subsequent pushes do not.

At first I thought that it could be that webpack wasn't getting ran at all so I added a specific call in my start script and moved the dependencies away from devDependencies. This ultimately didn't change anything even after I could see from the server that web pack was being ran and building. Below are the scripts I have setup in package.json aswell as my webpack.config.

//Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel build:prod lift",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development && sails lift",
    "start:debug": "npm-run-all --parallel open:client debug",
    "open:client": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "npm run build:prod",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

//Webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    entry: "./assets/src/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/.tmp/public",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: "babel-loader",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        test: /\.css$/
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "assets/src/index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

I know that I haven't employed best practices for production webpack but for now I just want to get it working on my server. My next step is to fine tune production webpack to give me the smallest bundle file possible but for right now I need to get webpack to rebundle the assets instead of using an old file. I'm sorta new to front and back end javascript development so a lot of this is new to me and I just initially setup webpack as quickly as possible.

**Update - Solved**
It seems that my issue was that my browser had cached the previous bundle.js file. Looking into a long term solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the old build folder before re-bundling a new one. add a prepare npm hook to execute the script before packaging

```
"scripts": {
    "prepare": "rm -rf /.tmp/public",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel build:prod lift",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development && sails lift",
    "start:debug": "npm-run-all --parallel open:client debug",
    "open:client": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "npm run build:prod",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

or

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf /.tmp/public",
    ...
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build:prod",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode production"
}
```